# Spark: how to get all configuration parameters

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to find out what configuration parameters my spark app is executing with. Is there a way to get all parameters, including the default ones?

E.g. if you execute "set;" on a Hive console, it'll list full Hive configuration. I'm looking for an analogous action/command for Spark.

**UPDATE**:
I've tried the solution proposed by karthik manchala. I'm getting these results. As far as I know, these are not all parameters. E.g. this one spark.shuffle.memoryFraction (and a lot more) is missing.

```
scala> println(sc.getConf.getAll.deep.mkString("\n"));
(spark.eventLog.enabled,true)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,1)
(spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_HOSTS,...)
(spark.repl.class.uri,http://...:54157)
(spark.tachyonStore.folderName,spark-46d43c17-b0b3-4b61-a017-a186075849ca)
(spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_URI_BASES,http://...)
(spark.driver.host,...l)
(spark.yarn.jar,local:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly.jar)
(spark.yarn.historyServer.address,http://...:18088)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout,60)
(spark.serializer,org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer)
(spark.authenticate,false)
(spark.fileserver.uri,http://...:33681)
(spark.app.name,Spark shell)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors,30)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,3)
(spark.ui.filters,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter)
(spark.driver.port,46781)
(spark.shuffle.service.enabled,true)
(spark.master,yarn-client)
(spark.eventLog.dir,hdfs://.../user/spark/applicationHistory)
(spark.app.id,application_1449242356422_80431)
(spark.driver.appUIAddress,http://...:4040)
(spark.driver.extraLibraryPath,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.schedulerBacklogTimeout,1)
(spark.shuffle.service.port,7337)
(spark.executor.id,<driver>)
(spark.jars,)
(spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true)
(spark.executor.extraLibraryPath,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native)
(spark.yarn.am.extraLibraryPath,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.7-1.cdh5.4.7.p0.3/lib/hadoop/lib/native)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
sparkContext.getConf().getAll();
```

Comment: This only gets properties that have been explicitly assigned a value. It does not get properties that use a default value.

Comment: Exactly, I'm also the same answer as @Travis

Comment: Did you find an answer

Comment: For default values, see here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#viewing-spark-properties